# C++: new base class,but it can access the derived class's property

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class animal
{

  public:
   void breathe()
   {
     cout << "breathe!" << endl;
   }

   int height;
};
class fish : public animal
{
  public:
   void breathe()
   {
     cout << "fish breathe!" << endl;
   }
   int weight;
};
int main()
{
  animal *p_animal = new animal();
  fish *p_fish = (fish *)p_animal;

  p_fish->breathe();
  p_fish->weight = 2;
  cout << p_fish->weight; //I new a animal instance,but why does it has weight property?

  int temp;
  cin >> temp;
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't stop you from shooting yourself. You went out of your way to do this and the code is now buggy.

Comment: You are using memory you are not supposed to. Your code is subject to undefined behavior.

Comment: It doesn't have a `weight` property, you're just pretending that it does. Pretending can keep you happy for a while, until reality reminds you that the world isn't like that. Then you learn not to lie to the compiler.

Comment: Do not use C-style conversions like `(fish*)` in C++. The only way to correctly perform convertion here is `dynamic_cast` which will return `nullptr`. You are likely doing `reinterpret_cast` here which works like "here are some memory, let's pretend it is `fish`".

Comment: @myaut : it's not the only way. Some times, you well know the real type, and then you can simply do a `static_cast` (for example, when you are in a `if` statement determined by a `typeid` equality). When the check is already done, `static_cast` is faster than `dynamic_cast`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some side comments on your code.**

In this example, you probably want virtual functions. See this modification of your code with some comments :

```
#include <iostream>

class Animal
{
  public:
    virtual ~Animal() {} // Always define virtual destructor in this case
    virtual void breathe() const  // This fonction doesn't modify the object
    {                             // then, add 'const' at the end
      std::cout << "breathe!" << std::endl;
    }
    unsigned int height; // An animal can't have a negative height ;-)
                         // then, use an unsigned type.
};

class Fish : public Animal
{
  public:
    virtual ~Fish() {}
    virtual void breathe() const
    {
      std::cout << "fish breathe!" << std::endl;
    }
    unsigned int weight;
};

int main()
{
  Animal* p_animal = new Animal;  // Don't put () for empty constructor
  Animal* p_fish = new Fish;

  p_animal->breathe(); // this prints "breathe!"
  p_fish->breathe();  // this prints "fish breathe!" even if the pointer is
                      // an pointer to Animal. It's the behaviour of virtual
                      // functions : when the code is executed, the real type
                      // is checked and the corresponding function is called.

  p_fish->height = 10;  // This works
  // p_fish->weight = 5;  // This doesn't compile, it's an pointer to Animal

  Fish* p_real_fish = dynamic_cast<Fish*>(p_fish);
  p_real_fish->height = 10;  // This works
  p_real_fish->weight = 5;  // This works too

  delete p_animal;  // Don't forget to release the memory !
  delete p_fish;
}
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

As various commenters have pointed out, you're tricking the compiler into letting you do this.

The key line is

```
fish *p_fish = (fish *)p_animal;
```

This line basically forces the compiler to accept that *whatever* p_animal was pointing to, it's now pointing to a fish.

If you are able to access the properties there, then it's basically chance, and a different compiler might give you different results.

If you had written

```
fish *p_fish = p_animal;
```

Then compiler would have complained.